# Comparing two ranges of numbers in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, sprite

I am trying to figure out a way to compare two ranges of numbers in an if statement. The method I am working on returns a boolean to see if two sprites overlap, and I am currently thinking of implementing it by comparing their locations. The sprites are 60X60, and their x and y locations reference their top left corners.

Am I going about this the wrong way? If not, whats the best way to compare these ranges via if statements?

EDIT:
Here is my attempt. I thought it was working, but it seems like it does not always pick up overlaps correctly.

```
public boolean overlaps(Sprite s)
{
    if ( (s.getX() >= this.getX()) && (s.getX() <= (this.getX() + 60)) )
    {
        if ( (s.getY() >= this.getY()) && (s.getY() <= (this.getY() + 60)) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        else if ( (s.getY() + 60) >= this.getY() && ((s.getY() + 60) <= (this.getY() + 60)) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    else if ( (s.getX() + 60) >= this.getX() && ((s.getX() + 60) <= (this.getX() + 60)) )
    {
        if ( (s.getY() + 60) >= this.getY() && ((s.getY() + 60) <= (this.getY() + 60)) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        else if ( (s.getY() >= this.getY()) && (s.getY() <= (this.getY() + 60)) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Show us your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Use the equals method in `Point` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this may be to leverage what is already available in the Java libraries.  One possibility is to use [`Rectangle.intersects(x, y, w, h)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects-java.awt.Rectangle-)

First define some constants for the width and height:

```
public class Sprite
{
  private static final int SPRITE_WIDTH  = 60;
  private static final int SPRITE_HEIGHT = 60;
```

Then the implementation of `overlaps` should be pretty easy using the `intersects` method:

```
  public boolean overlaps(Sprite s)
  {
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(this.getX(), this.getY(), SPRITE_WIDTH, SPRITE_HEIGHT);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(s.getX(), s.getY(), SPRITE_WIDTH, SPRITE_HEIGHT);
    return r1.intersects(r2);
  }
```